# The gmail api refresh token does not work

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the Gmail api to send e-mails from my Oracle database.
After a while, the Oauth2 token expires and the token needs to be refreshed with, using the refresh token.
All of this works fine (in both Postman and Oracle).
When the mail has not been used for a while ( a few weeks) the refresh token doesn't work anymore.
Then I need to get a new authorization code etc. It seems as if the gmail-api revokes its grant after a certain time.
Is there a way to work around this ?

thanks in advance.

Servé

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things which can cause a refresh token to expire here are my top three.

Applications that are still in testing, and have not bee though the google verification process will have their refresh tokens expired within in two weeks.

[image]

If the user changes their password this will also cause a refresh token to expire when using the gmail scopes.

If you authorize the app, then authorize it again you get two refresh tokens both will work,  you can have up to fifty outstanding refresh tokens once you have hit that number the first one will be expired, as you can maximum have fifty outstanding refresh tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your quick repsonse.
My publishing status is still in testing phase, so that must be the problem.

When I want to change to Production status, I am required to create documentation etc.  However, I only want to use this api myself in my own application. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Authorize the application ever few weeks, and get a new refresh token when it expires.

Comment: I dont like to authorize every two weeks. So I would like to go to production status. Can  anyone explain why I have to do the following? An official link to your app's Privacy Policy
A YouTube video showing how you plan to use the Google user data you get from scopes
A written explanation telling Google why you need access to sensitive and/or restricted user data
All your domains verified in Google Search Console

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the possible refresh token expiration reasons here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#expiration